# how to read the data from source if replica down in spring boot + mysql+ connectorj

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have one master and 2 slaves and my data source URL will be like the below.
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:replication://source,replica1, replica2/test_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&**allowReplicaDownConnections=true**&**readFromSourceWhenNoReplicas=true**

I after the application started, intentionally stopped slaves and getting exceptions while read operations failing and getting exception.

Exception:
2022-08-12 13:33:39,821 LAP-0302-RMAC.local AMS unknown_node main Severity=WARN  [,] c.z.h.p.ProxyConnection.checkException() - HikariPool-1 - Connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ha.ReplicationMySQLConnection@5e6ad84c marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(0)
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed. Connection closed after inability to pick valid new connection during load-balance.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ha.LoadBalancedConnectionProxy.invokeMore(LoadBalancedConnectionProxy.java:548)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ha.MultiHostConnectionProxy.invoke(MultiHostConnectionProxy.java:481)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ha.MultiHostMySQLConnection.setAutoCommit(MultiHostMySQLConnection.java:490)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ha.ReplicationConnectionProxy.invokeMore(ReplicationConnectionProxy.java:315)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ha.MultiHostConnectionProxy.invoke(MultiHostConnectionProxy.java:481)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy148.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(ProxyConnection.java:388)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(HikariProxyConnection.java)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.begin(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:67)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:263)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:236)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:86)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:183)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:401)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy186.findById(Unknown Source)

Comment: Can you please also add the exceptions with the stacktraces

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, added Exception